# Stop animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, uianimation

I have a cycle animate in `viewController`

```
- (void)moveAnimating
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
        _backgroundView.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x , self.center.y - kMoveDistanceHeight);
     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (_backgroundView.animating)
        {
           [_backgroundView moveAnimating];
        }
    }];
}
```

I want stop this animate When the `viewController` `viewWillDisappear`:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _backgroundView.animating = NO;
    [_backgroundView.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

Because the animation is conflict with `dismissViewcontrollerAnimation`.

Question:

```
[_backgroundView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

not work...

How to stop the animation？

Help me,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are canceling animations correctly:

```
[_backgroundView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

But you might forget about importing QuartzCore.h:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

If it doesn't help try this:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[_backgroundView.layer removeAllAnimations];
[CATransaction commit];
```

If it doesn't help try to add this line to the code above:

```
[CATransaction flush];
```

Answer (score 0):

Te solution from @KlimczakM didn't work for me.

I'm running an 'animateWithDuration' block that moves and image, and I use the next code to pause and resume the animation:

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
   CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
   layer.speed = 0.0;
   layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer {
   CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
   layer.speed = 1.0;
   layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
   layer.beginTime = 0.0;
   CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
   layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

This is from the Apple Documentation at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW14).